# I need to tockenize string of a java code to its blocks

Tags: java, tokenize, stringtokenizer

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();   
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(5000));    
    byte[] message = "Oh Hai!".getBytes();      
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
    socket.send(packet);
  }
}
```

**I have this code as a string and I need to get its methods statements loops for separate arrays**
Can any body suggest a solution

Comment: Please check your formatting...

Comment: Also check out http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/

Comment: this this code is from stack overflow data dump
I make it as a string

Comment: Well, it's considered polite here to format it correctly, even if it's copypasta...   You should consider doing that.

Comment: I don't know ...
can any body give me the link of Download the Java.g and the JavaTreeParser.g files

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `StreamTokenizer` to analyze a stream (e.g. StringReader).

Here you are an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader("public static void main(String[] args){"));

        tokenizer.parseNumbers();

        tokenizer.wordChars('_', '_');

        tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(true);
        tokenizer.ordinaryChars(0, ' ');
        tokenizer.slashSlashComments(true);
        tokenizer.slashStarComments(true);

        int token;

        try {
            while( (token = tokenizer.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                if(token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
                    System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Please handle this exception
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
public
static
void
main
String
args
```

Please have a look at this for further details:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Comment: Doing that and then trying to assemble those strings into AST elements ("statements", "blocks", "loops") is a path to at-best-misery.   You're effectively suggesting he write his own Java parser and use `StreamTokenizer` as a lexer.   It's not going to work (unless OP has deep understanding of compiler theory and a lot of time).